# how to save random generator code image to folder

Tags: php, kohana, barcode

I generated the barcode by using php in kohana 2.3.

I can able to view only the barcode image.

I can't able to store that image into one folder.

I used that below code

```
 $coupon_code =  text::random($type = 'alnum', $length = 6);                                                       $img = $this->code128BarCode($coupon_code);
      ob_start();
      imagepng($img);
      //Get the image from the output buffer
     $output_img     =   ob_get_clean();
     echo '<img type="file" name="barcode" style="height:30px;width:100px;" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($output_img) . '" />'; exit;
```

help me to store that image into folder.

Answer (score 0):

You must use imagepng in correct manner to save image some where. Like

```
imagepng($img, $saved_file_path);
```

See [imagepng tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) for more.